# SQL Server Reporting Services - Pass values from a table from report 1 to report 2

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I've a two table in a Report (let's call it Report 1). This tables have 3 datasets to fill the fields with calculations values.

Now, I want to get the values calculated in Reporter 1 and copy/extract to another Reporter..

Obvsiosly I can do this creating the same data sources and datasets and re-creating the tables again, but I'm sure that is a easier way to do this. Pass values to Variables?

Thanks!

Comment: you can definitely use this `Report1` in `Reoprt2` by using `sub-report` methodology, but data sets are specific to repots unless they are shared, You can create a shared data set and use that in Report1 and Report2.

Comment: @M.Ali thansk for your response :) Imagine this scenario: In table 1 (report 1) I've two fields. if the Value A is positive then "Green" else "Red". Same case to Value B. 
And in Report 2 want to read the table only the values that are positive. Can I save that values in variables and pass to the report 2?

Comment: You can do this only if you have report 2 as a sub report to report 1 and then pass through a variable to report 2. In this case i'd just copy the logic from report 1 and move it to report 2 if they aren't linked by sub reports.

Comment: Would probably be easier to do this in your sql proc.

Comment: @Snowlockk using a Store Procedure in SSRS?